# Can multiple instances of same powershell script write log into same Log file

Tags: powershell, logging, parallel-processing

I am facing an issue with logs when using **PowerShell Transcript**.
I have to run a script in multiple instances and it all needs to append logs into the same log file but what happens is that when multiple instances of the scripts are running first started instance logs are only written to the log file.

Is there a feature in PowerShell that I have missed? How can I get logs of each instance onto the same Log file?

Conditions:
**I can only use a single log file and all the instances should write logs to that file**

Sample Code

```
Start-Transcript -Append  $logDirectory
```

Comment: I did a few experiments - logging from multiple instances to the same file doesn't seem to be supported by `Start-Transcript`. You need to find a different solution, e. g. `Out-File -Append` (inefficient) or directly work with .NET file streams to open a file with write-sharing flag.

Comment: The first instance will set a write lock. To enable another script to use the same log file, you most close the file in between.